# JavaScript function not working at all when putting sections inside div

Tags: javascript, html

I created a function that works when I remove the div with class "scroll-container", but whenever I put the sections inside the div, the function is not working at all, how can I solve this?

Literally you remove the div code and it works, not sure if I have to call the div class on my JavaScript somehow...

HTML

```
<body>
<div class="scroll-container">
            <section style="background-image: url('https://static.vecteezy.com/system/resources/previews/005/267/025/original/mountain-landscape-with-silhouettes-of-forest-trees-perfect-to-use-for-background-dark-blue-color-silhouette-free-vector.jpg'); display: inline-block;" class="active" id="sec1">
            <div class="content">
             <h1>David Grillo</h1>
             <h2><b>Sobre Mí</b></h2>
            </div>
            </section>

             <section style="background-image: url('https://4kwallpapers.com/images/wallpapers/blue-mountains-foggy-mountain-range-landscape-scenery-5k-1920x1080-5939.jpg'); display: inline-block;" class="" >
                <div class="content">
                    <h1>David Grillo</h1>
                    <h2><b>Sobre Mí</b></h2>
                </div>
            
            </section>
            <section style="background-image: url('https://tesla-cdn.thron.com/delivery/public/image/tesla/ddc135ed-1638-40fb-8ab1-f8045059ecef/bvlatuR/std/4096x2560/Homepage-Model-X-Desktop-LHD'); display: inline-block;" class="" >
                <div class="content">
                    <h1>David Grillo</h1>
                    <h2><b>Sobre Mí</b></h2>
                </div>
            
            </section>
            <section style="background-image: url('https://tesla-cdn.thron.com/delivery/public/image/tesla/16b04537-a4be-4bf9-8637-86862a858da8/bvlatuR/std/2880x1800/_25-HP-SolarPanels-D'); display: inline-block;" class="" >
                <div class="content">
                    <h1>David Grillo</h1>
                    <h2><b>Sobre Mí</b></h2>
                </div>
            </section>
            <section style="background-image: url('https://tesla-cdn.thron.com/delivery/public/image/tesla/c877126e-0db5-409d-a412-04fc94b59b76/bvlatuR/std/2880x1800/HP-SR-Design-D'); display: inline-block;" class="" >
                <div class="content">
                    <h1>David Grillo</h1>
                    <h2><b>Sobre Mí</b></h2>
                </div>
            </section>
        
            <script src="dgscript.js" type="text/javascript"></script>     
        </div>    
        
    </body>
```

CSS

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'freedom';
    src: url(fonts/Mefika.ttf);
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 100;
}

html ::-webkit-scrollbar{
    display: none;
}

html{
    
    scroll-behavior: smooth;
    
    
    
}

.scroll-container {
    overflow-y: scroll;
    height: 100vh;
    scroll-snap-type: y mandatory;
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
    overflow-y: y mandatory;
}
 
  section {
    height: 100vh;
    object-fit: cover;
    object-position: center;
  }
  
  section {
    width: 100%;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center center;
    scroll-snap-align: start;
    scroll-snap-stop: always;
  }
  
  body {
    margin: 0;
    transition: 1s;
  }
```

JavaScript

```
document.lastScrollPosition = 0;
document.lastCentered = 0;
document.onWayTo = null;
let timeout
var wheel_timer = 0

$(document).ready(function() {

document.addEventListener('scroll', () => {
  const direction = window.pageYOffset - document.lastScrollPosition > 0 ? 'down' : 'up';
  const sections = [...document.querySelector('scroll-container'),document.querySelectorAll('section')];
  event.preventDefault();

  if (document.onWayTo === null) {
    const destIndex = direction === 'up' ? document.lastCentered - 1 : document.lastCentered + 1;
    if (destIndex >= 0 && destIndex < sections.length) {
      console.log({destIndex,direction});
      document.onWayTo = destIndex;
      window.scroll(1, sections[destIndex].offsetTop);
    }
  }
  
  
  var timer = setInterval( () => {
  sections.forEach((section,index) => {
    
    if (window.pageYOffset === section.offsetTop) {
      clearInterval(timer);
      document.lastCentered = index;
      section.className = 'active'
      
      if (document.onWayTo === index) {
        document.onWayTo = null;
      }
    } else {
      section.className = '';
    }
    
    const content = document.querySelector("html");
    
       
    document.addEventListener("wheel", () => {
        
        
        event.preventDefault();
         // getting the scrolling speed.
         let deltaY = event.deltaY;
         
         // decreasing the scrolling speed by 50 times
         let speed = event.deltaY / 0.3;
         
         // scrolling the content of the div element
         content.scrollTop += speed;
        console.log(deltaY);
        
         
      },{passive:false});
    
 
  
  })
  
}, 500);

  console.log(direction);
  document.lastScrollPosition = window.pageYOffset;


/* scroll limit */
let page = document.querySelector("html")


event.deltaY = 0

})

})
```

Comment: Adding event listeners inside an event listener is a sign of potential trouble. The method always **adds** a listener without removing any previously added, and all of the registered handlers will be called on an event.

Comment: Yeah, I did put the wheel event listener inside the scroll event listener to test out something, but anyways, the important part is the scroll event listener, that function makes so that when I scroll between sections, the section showing on the screen becomes active, and I am trying to fix a scroll animation with a scroll-snapping on CSS that I must put the sections inside a div, but when doing so, the scroll event listener is not working.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to select the element with the class "scroll-container" using document.querySelector, but you forgot to add a dot before "scroll-container" to indicate that it is a class selector. The correct code should be:

```
// Correct code
const sections = [...document.querySelectorAll('.scroll-container section')];
```